# Why is "width=device-width" totally not working?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have a problem with setting media queries on devices. It doesn't work at all. It works like normal width. Why is that?

```
<meta charset="UTF-8" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, width=device-width">
```

And this is how I use it:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
    background-color: lightblue;
}
```

Comment: "on devices" what devices?

Comment: "It works like normal width" — What does that mean?

Comment: could you include more code of your html and css or a fiddle??

Comment: "And this is how I use it" — What result do you expect to get from what code? What result do you actually get?

Comment: I'm trying to set this color on devices like mobile, tablet and desktop, but it works only on desktop.

Comment: What mobile device do you expect to have a width of more than 600 CSS pixels?

Comment: This is only an example. It doesn't work at any width.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is very simple. You didn't put `background-color: lightblue;` in a tag 
it should be in something like a `html` or `body` tag.

You should also update your meta tag to

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Your code should look something like this:

```css
html{
  background-color:red;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  html{
    background-color: lightblue;
    }
}
```

```html
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

If you want the webpage to turn light blue when it is smaller then 600px you should swap the two colors

For more info you can go to [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp) they explain media queries very clearly.

Comment: I did that and it affects mobile devices. I mean every mobile device has this lightblue color, which is weird.

Comment: what are you trying to reacht then?

Comment: because that is good that they turned lightblue that means that they are bigger than 600 px if they are smaller than 600 px the page will turn red

Comment: I'm trying to change color on every devices with the with bigger than 600px, but it affects every mobile device, even those with less width than 600px.

Comment: can you share a fiddle of all your code?? else I can't help you

Comment: It's clear for me. It tried to upload my code to jdfiddle but it works like you said. But locally it works like it doesn't detect that it is a device. Can it be related with some webpack loaders?

Comment: Does it work if you replace your `<meta charset="UTF-8" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, width=device-width">` tag with `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` this meta tag

Comment: i always make two `meta` tags like this `<meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`